# where can I find an older version of Creative Suite

Tags: adobe-creative-suite

I currently have CS version 1. All I use is Illustrator and Photoshop and by no means do I ever push the envelope of what they can do. I'm actually happy with this version of photoshop but Illustrator takes my Win7 out of Aero which is annoying. It also has some intermittent display issues. Anyway, my copy of CS is too old to qualify for upgrade pricing and I really don't need, or can really afford, the latest. Where can I get a legal, older copy of CS that works well with Win7?

If I see something on ebay, what do I need to look for to ensure the license will be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buying on ebay is pretty much a guarantee the license will not be valid. The way to minimize this risk is to purchase only from *very* high ranked sellers who sell a lot of this software.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it isn't a copy or purchased under a licensing contract, any normal boxed version off of eBay should both be good and licensed.

All I can suggest to look for is that the seller says it is legal/legit and then you have done your part. If it isn't or you notice something dodgy after you get it, simply complain and get your money back.